# gparted disk partition wont resize

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

hey im really new to ubuntu but over the past few weeks I have brought some old machines back from the dead by running ubuntu rather than windows and im loving it, even convinced my dad to get rid of winidows 10. 
So I decided to dual boot my main pc running windows 7 and focal fossa yesterday. left all the partitioning up to ubuntu installer and im already out of space, it gave me 9gb. now im having difficulty booting ubuntu and getting loads of warnings about low disk space.

been in to windows disk manager and unallocated some space, made a bootable gparted usb which i cant get to run keep getting a message saying no bootable partition in table, then remembered i have a bootable usb that i installed ubuntu with(literally hours earlier).

so im on my live usb in gparted, and i cant resize the ubuntu partition, made a bit more unalocated space in gparted but still cant make my ubuntu partition any bigger.

[image: gparted screenshot]

what am i doing wrong? would i be better just reinstalling ubuntu (im 6 hours in and 5 of them have been spent trying to resize a partition)

thanks

Comment: You can't resize because ther is no unallocated space near the partition. If you move `/dev/sda3` to the left, it should be fixed.

Comment: @Pilot6 That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Move `/dev/sda3` to the left, then you'll be able to resize `/dev/sda4`.

Comment: That won't work.

Comment: @heynnema Why won't it work?

Comment: OP wants to add to their /dev/sda5. How does this answer accomplish that?

Comment: @heynnema The question was how to resize sda4. sda5 is inside.

Comment: You're answer is incomplete/wrong, Reread the question. re: *"cant make my ubuntu partition any bigger"*. Resizing /dev/sda4 won't accomplish this by itself. Their *"ubuntu partition"* is /dev/sda5, and your answer doesn't even mention /dev/sda5. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

**Note**: This particular re-partition is slightly complicated because of the extended partition.

**Note**: If this is a newer UEFI computer, this disk should really be in GPT partition format, not MBR format.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **move** /dev/sda3 partition all the way left

  - reboot now to test if moving this partition caused a problem booting Windows or Ubuntu
  - if it boots ok, then return here and continue
- **resize** the left side of /dev/sda4 extended partition all the way left

  - this might be tricky as it's an extended partition
  - if you can't do this, stop, and contact me for an alternate procedure
- **move** /dev/sda5 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sda5 all the way right
- click the Apply icon